# Checking content and moving files recursively from a directory

Tags: bash, shell, unix, xpath

I have a directory with header and payload xml files named like(no .xml extension is there):

```
File1
File1_PAYLOAD
File2
File2_PAYLOAD
```

I need to check whether the header file contains two attributes which if present the file should be moved to another directory along with its PAYLOAD file.
I'm using xmllint --xpath to check the attributes, it has a **headers** tag inside which are a bunch of **header** tags, my query:

```
xmllint --xpath "boolean(//*[local-name()='headers' and *[local-name()='header'][@name='Type' and @value='AAAA'] and *[local-name()='header'][@name='Update' and @value='DONE']])
```

The xpath query works fine and returns a true/false according to whether the attributes are present or not. Problem comes with how to iterate over only header files and move them. I've tried to use find like:

```
#!/bin/bash
dest="/tmp/proc"
loc="/tmp/files"
find $loc -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 ! -name '*_PAYLOAD' -exec xmllint --xpath "boolean(//*[local-name()='headers' and *[local-name()='header'][@name='Type' and @value='AAAA'] and *[local-name()='header'][@name='Update' and @value='DONE']]) " {} \; -exec mv {} $dest \; -exec mv {}_PAYLOAD $dest \;
```

But this query moves the files even when my xpath query return false, I think maybe find -exec is taking the true/false returned as an string hence true and still proceed to the next exec. So I tried find with sh -c, so that I can incorporate some sort of if and else structure:

```
    #!/bin/bash
    dest="/tmp/proc"
    loc="/tmp/files"
    find $loc -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 ! -name '*_PAYLOAD' -exec sh -c '
        for file do
        stat=$(xmllint --xpath "boolean(//*[local-name()='headers' and *[local-name()='header'][@name='Type' and @value='AAAA'] and *[local-name()='header'][@name='Update' and @value='DONE']]) " "$file" | grep 'true' | wc -l)
        if [ "$stat" -eq 1 ]
            mv "$file" "$dest"
            mv "$file"_PAYLOAD "$dest"
    done' sh {} \;
```

but this gives an error :

```
sh: -c: line 6: syntax error near unexpected token `done' sh: -c: line 6: `done'
```

This syntax I saw from https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/321697/why-is-looping-over-finds-output-bad-practice/321753#321753

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can try below, please check if this works for you:

```
#!/bin/bash
    dest="/tmp/proc"
    loc="/tmp/files"
    for i in $(find "$loc" -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 ! -name "*_PAYLOAD" -exec basename "{}" \;)
    do
        stat=$(xmllint --xpath "boolean(//*[local-name()='headers' and *[local-name()='header'][@name='Type' and @value='AAAA'] and *[local-name()='header'][@name='Update' and @value='DONE']]) "$i"
      if [[ "$stat" == "true" ]]
        then
          mv "$i" "$dest"
          mv "$i"_PAYLOAD "$dest"
      fi
    done
```

Comment: Hi, your given code gives the error: 
warning: failed to load external entity "FILENAME"     -- here this filename is getting displayed without the actual path before it, hence my xpath doesn't work as it need the full path of the file, as stat was empty when I tried to echo it.
Tried removing the basename attribute to get the full path but then got the error:
find 'FILENAME-with full path' : permission denied.
it works fine if I replace " -exec basename "{}" " with a simple " -exec echo {} "
Thanks for the syntax☺.

Comment: @KushalSharma: Glad that it worked for you! I believe just to reduce the complexity, you can replace the `find` with this: `for i in /tmp/files/*_PAYLOAD; do .......done`...maybe you can try and it should work. Thanks!

Comment: I've tried that too, the next solution posted was based on that only, it's a very clean and simple solution I just can understand what this ->   [[ -e "$f" ]] || continue     is doing.

Answer (score 0):

## edited

*Another* take on it -
`xmllint` apparently does not return that boolean as its exit code, and is ugly as hell, so I farmed it out to a function.

```
tst() { xmllint --xpath "boolean(//*[local-name()='headers' and *[local-name()='header'][@name='Type' and @value='AAAA'] and *[local-name()='header'][@name='Update' and @value='DONE']])" "$1"; }

for p in /tmp/files/*_PAYLOAD
do f=${p%_PAYLOAD}
   [[ -e "$f" && true == "$(tst $f)" ]] && mv $f $p /tmp/proc
done
```

Comment: This is moving the files even when xpath returns false, I've just started scripting did not know how to trim "PAYLOAD" and use the rest of the string. Can you explain what this is doing :  [[ -e "$f" ]] || continue
Thank you.

Comment: Saved what xmllint was returning in a variable and added a IF condition, then it works fine.

Comment: As I said, assuming the return sets the exit code. Apparently doesn't. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

By using [xidel](/questions/tagged/xidel) (and its integrated [EXPath File Module](http://expath.org/spec/file)) instead of `xmllint` I *believe* there's no need for a Bash script at all.

```
xidel -s --xquery '
  let $dest:="/tmp/proc/",
      $loc:="/tmp/files/"
  for $x in file:list($loc,false(),"*_PAYLOAD")
  where doc($loc||$x)//*[
    local-name()="headers" and
    *[local-name()="header"][@name="Type" and @value="AAAA"] and
    *[local-name()="header"][@name="Update" and @value="DONE"]
  ]
  return
  file:move($loc||$x,$dest||$x)
'
```